# How to validate multi list

Tags: c#, list

I have the following code to select the record from the database:

```
 public List<string>[] Select(string Command)
    {
        string query = Command;

        //Create a list to store the result
        List<string>[] list = new List<string>[2];
        list[0] = new List<string>();
        list[1] = new List<string>();


        //Open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Read the data and store them in the list
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                list[0].Add(dataReader["NIK"] + "");
                list[1].Add(dataReader["Password"] + "");                    
            }

            //close Data Reader
            dataReader.Close();

            //close Connection
            this.CloseConnection();

            //return list to be displayed
            return list;


        }
        else
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
```

I have 2 column in my table, which is `NIK` and `Password` and the table has 2 rows which is `1`,`1` and `2`,`1`.

How do I validate if the list contain `NIK` = 2 and `Password` = 1? How do I know if the select statement is successfully get the record from my table? How do I print the multi list into textbox ?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `Dictionary<string, string>` instead of an array of `List<string>`s.

You can then print all the records:

```
foreach (var pair in dictionary)
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + ", " pair.Value);
```

The first string in every dictionary pair is a key and the second one is a value.

Answer (score 0):

> how do i validate if the list contain NIK = 2 and Password = 1 ?

Go through the list and check. For example, using [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx).

> how do i know if the select statement is successfully get the record from my table ?

If no exception was thrown.

> how do i print the multi list into textbox ?

Construct a string from the values returned from the database (e.g. using [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)) and assign it to [TextBox.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text.aspx).

---

BTW, you should really consider enclosing the reader and connection in `using` block. This way, resources will be deterministically freed even in the case of exception.

Also, consider using type-specific getters to read the data from the reader (such as [GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getstring.aspx), [GetInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getint32.aspx) etc.).